# Rate limits on RSS feeds (youtube)

Tags: python, youtube, rss, rate-limiting

I am making a discord bot in python which would ping me whenever the YouTubers I wish to keep track of upload any video.
So at first, I thought of using the Youtube Api but I couldn't find anything for this specific topic. Then I found RSS feeds.
So my main question is, what are the rate limits on calling the URL (`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=xxx`)?
As the plan, I have in my mind is that I will make an HTTP request to the URL every x seconds, and if it sees any update, it pings me in my server.

Comment: I read in another question here on Stack Overflow about this subject and the response was similar to: add a paramter in the URL and the value of that new parameter would be a random number. Have you checked anything yet? - I don't think this feed/endpoint has a limit, but, I would be cautious about the amount of pings/requests I made for avoid be blacklisted...

Comment: @Marco Aurelio Fernandez Reyes Yes that's my worry too. I can test it by spamming the RSS feed but am worried that I might get IP banned.

Comment: reading again your question you said: `I will make an HTTP request to the URL every x seconds` - what if, instead making a lot of requests, check first the channel you want to get the data, check their publicationDate videos and see if there is a pattern of dates? - let's say the channel publish a new video every day or every 3 hours, you can use this timelapse and considered for configure your request to the feed of that channel. Just curious, did you keep working on this requirement? also, can you provide some example of the channel you want to check? - I want give it a try.

Comment: Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68203416/12511801) that mentions a similar requirement of yours. Good luck